# Guardar dato de una variable js en Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel y estoy intentando hacer un rating stars. Esta es la estructura.

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<h5>Elige una clasificación por estrellas</h5>
</div><br>
<div class="row justify-content-center rating" >

<li class="list-inline-item b1 click" value="5">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x "></i>
</li>
<li class="list-inline-item b2 click" value="4">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x "></i>
</li>
<li class="list-inline-item b3 click" value="3">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x "></i>
</li>
<li class="list-inline-item b4 click" value="2">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x "></i>
</li>
<li class="list-inline-item b5 click" value="1">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x "></i>
</li>

</div>
```

Lo que intento hacer es guardar el valor de acuerdo al que haya seleccionado el usuario. Con js obtengo el valor

```js
$(function(){

    $(".click").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).attr("value");
        alert(data);    
    });

});
```

Ahora, como puedo guardar esto en Laravel? 
El controlador para guardar los rating es

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rating = new Rating();
    $rating ->user_id = Auth::id();
    $rating ->profile_id = $request('profile_id');
    $rating ->rating = $request('rating');
    $rating ->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('mensaje', 'Su puntuacion ha sido enviada correctamente');
}
```

No se si me explico correctamente, cualquier ayudita cuenta, desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Enviarlo por AJAX

Comment: Recomendación no uses JQuery, mejor la api fetch o axios, trata algo y ya con dudas específicas te podemos ayudar

Comment: envia todos los datos por ajax, alla en el controlador los capturas pero debes definir un nombre o id en jquery